# can’t debug in qt sdk 1.2-during startup program exited with code 0x0

Tags: qt

Today I found that I could not debug in pure C projetc, but I could debug in qt gui project.
The error was “ during startup program exited with code 0×0”.
I was using Win 7 ultimate 64bit sp1. I had tried in another computer, it was the same.
My program ran when I was not trying to debug it. 
Could someone help?
Qt SDK 1.2 includes qt lib 4.8 and qt creator 2.4.1.

Comment: Debugger worked fine in qt creator 2.5 beta.

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck **run in terminal**, in Projects -> Run Options

Answer (score 0):

If the debugger does not work properly, try the following:

1. Make sure you use at least Qt Creator 2.1.
2. Make sure the debugger is set up properly. For more information, see [Setting Up Debugger](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.2/creator-debugger-engines.html).
3. In the Debug mode, select Windows > Views > Debugger Log to open the Debugger Log view. Browse the contents of the pane on the right hand side to find out what went wrong. Always attach the contents of the pane to debugger-related questions to the Qt Creator mailing list (qt-creator@trolltech.com) or paste them to creator.pastebin.com before asking questions in the IRC (on the #qt-creator channel at FreeNode).

Comment: >=thread-group-exited,id="i1"
sThread group i1 exited
>&"During startup program exited with code 0x0.\n"
>73^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0x0."
dCOOKIE FOR TOKEN 73 ALREADY EATEN (InferiorSetupRequested). TWO RESPONSES FOR ONE COMMAND?
dNOTE: INFERIOR EXITED
dState changed from InferiorSetupRequested(4) to InferiorExitOk(16).
dState changed from InferiorExitOk(16) to InferiorShutdownOk(19).
dState changed from InferiorShutdownOk(19) to EngineShutdownRequested(20).
dQUEUE: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
sExecutable failed: During startup program exited with code 0x0.

Comment: dCALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
dINITIATE GDBENGINE SHUTDOWN IN STATE 0, PROC: 2
<75-gdb-exit
>&"No symbol table is loaded.  Use the \"file\" command.\n"
>74^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="<PENDING>",pending="\"main.cpp\":7",times="0",original-location="\"main.cpp\":7"}
dBREAKPOINT SYNCHRONIZATION NOT POSSIBLE IN CURRENT STATE

Comment: These are part of the contents in the Debugger Log View.